# How to create a recursive folder function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, filter

I need to create a function that takes 1 argument of type array from an api.
This taken argument is a non-inherited array.

A good example is a OS files list, where we have folders and infinite subfolders down the tree.
So, with the following data provided from the api we have something like:

```
data: [
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b949',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'FOLDER',
    },
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b948',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'STANDARD',
      parent: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b949'
    },
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b957',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'STANDARD',
      parent: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b948'
    }
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b936',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'STANDARD'
    }
```

The main goal is to build a new array in the frontend, but in an inherited way, getting as the basis a "parent: node_xxx-xxx" and "type: FOLDER/STANDARD" in child. Therefore, if the child element that has a "parent" attribute equals the ID attribute of another else item in the tree, this will be considered child.
Therefore a new array as the following will be build:

```
newData: [
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b949',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'FOLDER',
      children: [
          {
              id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b948',
              conditions: 'parent',
              type: 'FOLDER',
              parent: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b949',
              children: [
                  {
                      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b957',
                      conditions: 'string',
                      type: 'STANDARD',
                      parent: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b948'
                  }     
              ]
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b936',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'STANDARD'
    }
```

**type: STANDARD** = child item/sibling (that do not have children)
**type: FOLDER**   = parent item/sibling (that has children)

I ended up with something similar but only for the first folder level, by doing a **map** of the items and a **filter** that query for `parent === id`. After that the children of the children and the children of the children and so on... This is the part that the recursive concept comes in.

```
    const values = data.map((items) => ({
      ...items,
      children: data.filter((c) => c.parent === items.id)
    }))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce the array of nodes. Add each node to the `nodes` Map. Add all nodes without a `parent` to the `roots` array. If the node has a `parent` property, create the `parent`, and add it to the Map if it doesn't already exist. Add the current node to the parent. Grab the `roots` array when reduce is done:

```js
const data = [{"id":"node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b949","conditions":"string","type":"FOLDER"},{"id":"node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b948","conditions":"string","type":"FOLDER","parent":"node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b949"},{"id":"node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b957","conditions":"string","type":"STANDARD","parent":"node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b948"},{"id":"node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b936","conditions":"string","type":"STANDARD"}]

const result = data.reduce(({ nodes, roots }, o) => {   
  const node = o.type === 'FOLDER'
    ? { ...o, children: [], ...nodes.get(o.id) } // create folder node
    : o

  nodes.set(o.id, node) // set node to map

  if(!o.parent) roots.push(node) // if no parent add to roots
  else {
    // create parent if it doesn't exist
    if(!nodes.has(o.parent)) nodes.set({ id: o.parent, children: [] })

    // add child to parent
    nodes.get(o.parent).children.push(node)
  }

  return { nodes, roots }
}, { nodes: new Map, roots: [] }).roots // get the roots

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! @Ori Drori it worked as expected for any level now

Comment: Hey @Ori Drori! I found an issue regarding the position of the array. Like, for instance, if I have an item with ID 11 and the last sibling 14, and for some reason, the user wants to use ID 14 as its parent, it throws an error **ERROR TypeError: item.set is not a function**. I was debugging here and noticed **m.set**, in which "m" is not declared. I could test making it work by just changing the position of the item, and passing it as a previous sibling. I was wondering if it's possible to make an item as a parent in any position in the array, what do you think?

Comment: Renaming error. Change `m` to `nodes`. This line handles the parent out of order case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way I can think of, if I understand your question corectly:

- Create a map of ids to node for a faster look up
- Create root nodes, those are ndes without a parent
- Recursivly add children to a node
- Add children to all root nodes

```js
function folderStructure(data) {
  // Create a map of id to node for faster lookup
  const nodeMap = new Map();
  data.forEach(node => {
// Create a new object for each node that is not frozen
const newNode = { ...node };
nodeMap.set(newNode.id, newNode);
  });

  // Create the root nodes (nodes without a parent)
  const rootNodes = Array.from(nodeMap.values()).filter(node => !node.parent);

  // Recursive function to add children to a node
  function addChildren(node) {
if (node.type === 'FOLDER') {
  // Find all nodes with this node as parent
  const children = Array.from(nodeMap.values()).filter(child => child.parent === node.id);
  if (children.length > 0) {
    node.children = children;
    // Recursively add children to the child nodes
    children.forEach(child => addChildren(child));
  }
}
  }

  // Add children to all root nodes
  rootNodes.forEach(rootNode => addChildren(rootNode));

  return rootNodes;
}


//Testing:
const data = [
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b949',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'FOLDER',
    },
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b948',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'STANDARD',
      parent: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b949'
    },
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b957',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'STANDARD',
      parent: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b948'
    },
    {
      id: 'node_292f637b-b33d-4d3d-bc96-8afc7ee1b936',
      conditions: 'string',
      type: 'STANDARD'
    }
];

const newData = folderStructure(data);
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Hey there @esQmo_ Thanks for the answer!
I just tested, and I got an error at `node.children = children`. The following one:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property children, object is not extensible**

Comment: Your object is somehow 'frozen'?, Ok, then you create a new object for each node in the data array

Comment: I've updated the code to try addressing  ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property children, object is not extensible

Comment: Cool! It worked as expected for this one. Now, if I try to add a grandchild I come back to the same behavior. The same error ** ERROR TypeError: Cannot add property children, object is not extensible**

Comment: Which behaviour? The same error is being thrown ?